# How do you represent an array of generic types that are multiple levels deep?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following types and sample function in typescript...

```
export type ServiceMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]: MethodMap<T[K]> }

export type MethodMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]: (...args: any) => Promise<any> }

interface Request<TServiceMap extends ServiceMap<TServiceMap>, TService extends keyof TServiceMap, TMethod extends keyof TServiceMap[TService]> {
    service: TService,
    method: TMethod,
    // ...
}

function createRequest<TServiceMap extends ServiceMap<TServiceMap>, TService extends keyof TServiceMap, TMethod extends keyof TServiceMap[TService]>(service: TService, method: TMethod): Request<TServiceMap, TService, TMethod> {
    return;
}
```

How would you setup a function that would take an array of different requests? For example...

```
function send<TServiceMap extends ServiceMap<TServiceMap>>(requests: Request<TServiceMap, keyof TServiceMap, any>[]): void {
    return;
}

interface UserService {
    login: (userName: string) => Promise<string>,
    logout: () => Promise<void>
}

interface TicketService {
    create: (ticketNumber: number) => Promise<void>
}

interface MyServices {
    user: UserService,
    ticket: TicketService,
}

const requests = [
    createRequest<MyServices, 'user', 'login'>('user', 'login'),
    createRequest<MyServices, 'ticket', 'create'>('ticket', 'create')
]

send<MyServices>(requests);
```

Where 'any' is the type I am trying to properly define.

I have tried...

```
function send<TServiceMap extends ServiceMap<TServiceMap>, TService extends keyof TServiceMap, TMethod extends keyof TServiceMap[TService]>(requests: Request<TServiceMap, TService, TMethod>[]): void {
    return;
}
```

but this implies that all requests are the same.

I have also tried...

```
function send<TServiceMap extends ServiceMap<TServiceMap>>(requests: Request<TServiceMap, keyof TServiceMap, keyof TServiceMap[keyof TServiceMap]>[]): void {
    return;
}
```

but this gives me an expected never for the method type

Comment: I don't understand where `TServiceMap` is coming from, since you never actually pass a parameter of that type in any of your functions. If you call `createRequest()`, do you *manually* specify all three type argument? Please [edit] to show a [mre] which demonstrates how `createRequest()` works in practice, that includes calls with representative input and output.  It's possible that [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NV5Z7w) is what you're looking for, but until there's a [mre] here nobody but you can be certain. Please update the question and get back to me. Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz It looks like that's exactly what I'm looking for. I've updated my question. If you would like to post answer I'll accept it. Very slick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to make what's known as a *heterogeneous array*, where the element types are each constrained to some supertype, but where each element might be a different subtype of that constraint.  In your case each element is a `Request<M, KS, KM>` for some fixed `M` but possibly different `KS` and `KM` type arguments.

This is probably the canonical use case for so-called [existentially-quantified generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), where you'd like to be able to say "true for *some* type argument" instead of "true for *all* type arguments" like regular (universally-quantified) generics.  You can think of regular generics like infinite [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), whereas existential generics are like infinite [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  If TypeScript had existential generics, then each element of your array would be a `type SomeRequest<M> = <exists KS, exists KM> Request<M, KS, KM>` where `exists` is a hypothetical keyword that says you're declaring an existential generic instead of a universal one.  But TypeScript doesn't directly support such types, and neither do most languages with generics.  They *can* be encoded in TypeScript via a `Promise`-like callback, but luckily we don't need to go down that road here.

---

And that's because, for any given `M`, the `KS` and `KM` type arguments for `Request<M, KS, KM>` can't take on an infinite number of values. Instead they come from a particular finite set that depends on `M`.  So you don't need `type SomeRequest<M>` to be an *infinite* union, which requires existential generics.  It can just be a *finite* union, which TypeScript already supports.

We can build a nested *distributive object type* where we [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the properties `KS` in `keyof M` and the properties `KM` in `keyof M[KS]`, and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) them to get a union.  (If you have a key type `K` that is a union `K1 | K2 | K3`, then the distributive object type `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]` is equivalent to the union `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>`.)

That gives you:

```
type SomeRequest<M extends ServiceMap<M>> =
    { [KS in keyof M]:
        { [KM in keyof M[KS]]:
            Request<M, KS, KM>
        }[keyof M[KS]]
    }[keyof M]
```

So for any given `M`, a `SomeRequest<M>` will be a union of all types you'd like to support for `M`. And then `send` becomes

```
function send<M extends ServiceMap<M>>(
    requests: SomeRequest<M>[]): void {
    return;
}
```

---

Let's test it out:

When you call `send<MyServices>(requests)`, it means `requests` is checked against an array of `SomeRequest<MyServices>`.  Which is:

```
type Test = SomeRequest<MyServices>;
// type Test = 
//   Request<MyServices, "user", "login"> | 
//   Request<MyServices, "ticket", "create"> | 
//   Request<MyServices, "user", "logout">
```

A union of the three possible `Request` types you want to support. Since `requests`'s elements are among those union members, the call succeeds:

```
send<MyServices>(requests); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKwoDcCWBjYAWQEMwAeAFQD44BeOAbzgG0BpOHAOzgGthEIAMzgUAugC44hYDAAWEACYlyFNqJoBfAFBbQkWAmSppcxcso16TNh258BwsZIAUAOnfEoAcwDOk4pyIAJR0NAAKUBAAtjg+wGQBiJo6XDCYgsQEcABKwACOAK7APjBkhHCgaZwKPuiYuATmhFQANHCsaBUgVTW8-EJSbazllcDVtfYDhGxo6oxacItwcdj4wJIdLQtLUTLyChuEW0twAPSncO6uWtpaggWceDA4ENx4UMDEabmFxaXbixG3TGvQwq0apDKrQB7U6o3GfQcgxhwy6PQm-WE0w6oi0VGcKwa61hbV2pgO7UIQUkPyKJTKQzQQ2a8xOHxgBSg3E4BQANryAIQAbhuOjFqXSmVQAFUVmCiaylryIF4uC4CisAHLEXaSEpQLheEK0cKRGJxMj6w3Qk7KrwQAowFzG03RWLxLAQHAKKiirQSqAZLIUfB8GDytaKxbvT5pFzPPBhzUFKIAI0wkh5acwLrgETdFs93t9twDQeMiAjBFqDBhGozcFlmCrwGOSwTYckIcTMhbW1ueFeJTgH1+JVq9GYMJjX2AtL+ZUr9TWPjaAHJ61A1+u7Vw1-iNytt3A17vOGugm3ox9Z-P6YQl+DiuuOzJj2uZ2l98416+YO-P2AC8tFxHQkBQdBojnfI6VKIF0TqJ8mioSwYWsDpbERKYJBhE50PKLgsKxGZRBwk5yKWO84MZZlfQoxYNGYSZiJxXETkY5ipFA+5HmeV5lhBMo0RBWoW2Q-EYVHWC-Eg3YqKhZhRGpOAiwUKMRxkTlOBFW5wNQCg-joWToLHODHyJHwqBFc5DAggzh3oLQbMWeSHxbVc4AAIk3Ty2k8s9PJoAAfOAnIuFyYIXNzl2rPy-18rzAMCuAQrCyjIvvcyVz8ny-LtB0YECnQ4mqRd3PxKS-h8IIhTOC4IB4YhEC0IA)

Comment: This works great for a stand alone function but has issues when moved into a class and called from another function. [link](https://tsplay.dev/m3qPqw)

Comment: Generics and unions don't mix, well so if the use case requires generics then the big union won't work directly.  Are you asking me to do something about it? If so I would have hoped to hear such things before spending time on an answer. If not maybe you might want to post a new followup question which demonstrates use cases you care about?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you essentially need a way to express that each element in the array is a valid Request for some service and method within the ServiceMap, without requiring that all elements are requests for the same service and method.

Here's an approach that uses a generic function where the generic parameter extends ServiceMap, and it simplifies the method type constraint to allow any method from any service without tying it down too specifically:

```
function send<TServiceMap extends ServiceMap<any>>(requests: Request<TServiceMap, keyof TServiceMap, string>[]): void {
    // Implementation
}
```

In this variant, TMethod is simplified to string, which means you lose some of the type safety regarding the method names. This is a trade-off: you gain flexibility in the function's usage at the cost of not enforcing method names to be valid for the specified service at compile time.